# Split a string in shell scripting explaination

Tags: string, shell, zsh

I want to extract the directory. I have used the below mentioned shell script.

```
line='create word=/some/directory/name'
dir=${${${line##*=}#"'"}%"'"}
```

Though, it is working for me, I want to know the working of the 2nd line.
How exactly string split occur in the shell scripting.

Comment: What shell? `bash: ${${${line##*=}#"'"}%"'"}: bad substitution`

Comment: and `${line##*=}` is sufficient: the single quotes are removed by the shell, so they are  not part of the value in $line

Comment: using **zsh**.  I tried using `${line##*=}` and echoed the value. The echoed string contained single quotes. I am not sure if these quotes are internally removed while using the string.

Comment: in zsh `echo ${line##*=}` does not display any single quotes for me. You must have been doing something different.

Answer (score 1):

These constructs are known as "Parameter Substitutions".

For example (directly from the Bash documentation):

> **${var##Pattern}** Remove from `$var` the longest part of `$Pattern` that matches the front end of `$var`.

- [Parameter Substitutions in Bash](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)
- [Parameter Substitutions in Zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_12.html)

Comment: Since the question is tagged [tag:zsh] (now), it is best to refer to the `zsh` documentation since this is an area where `zsh` is radically different from `bash` in some respects — `zsh` allows nested application of parameter substitutions in a way that `bash` does not.   That said, individual steps are equivalent; it is just that you can't do the nested operations in `bash`.